# Sort Method Not Working Properly For Large number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of arrays consisting of around 20 values as below,

```
var myArray = [
            ["2017-01", "Female", "671950.00"],
            ["2017-01", "Male", "322800.00"],
            ["2017-02", "Male", "323977.00"],
            ["2017-02", "Female", "671375.00"],
            ["2017-03", "Male", "326515.00"],
            ["2017-03", "Female", "683646.00"],
            ["2017-04", "Male", "326642.00"],
            ["2017-04", "Female", "684820.00"],
            ["2017-05", "Female", "687627.00"],
            ["2017-05", "Male", "330966.00"],
            ["2017-06", "Male", "330290.00"],
            ["2017-06", "Female", "686022.00"],
            ["2017-07", "Male", "326663.00"],
            ["2017-07", "Female", "679277.00"],
            ["2017-08", "Female", "684451.00"],
            ["2017-08", "Male", "329804.00"],
            ["2017-09", "Female", "686584.00"],
            ["2017-09", "Male", "330300.00"],
            ["2017-10", "Female", "658154.00"],
            ["2017-10", "Male", "316671.00"]
          ];
```

I am grouping the above code with the first element of array also the second element of array is sorted with respect to the group.
For this I have written the below code,but this works fine for only ten elements in array as shown below,

```
var myArray = [
            ["2017-01", "Female", "671950.00"],
            ["2017-01", "Male", "322800.00"],
            ["2017-02", "Male", "323977.00"],
            ["2017-02", "Female", "671375.00"],
            ["2017-03", "Male", "326515.00"],
            ["2017-03", "Female", "683646.00"],
            ["2017-04", "Male", "326642.00"],
            ["2017-04", "Female", "684820.00"],
            ["2017-05", "Female", "687627.00"],
            ["2017-05", "Male", "330966.00"],

          ];

          myArray  = myArray.sort(function (a, b) {  

             return a[0] == b[0] && a[1] > b[1];

        });
```

If I use the previous array with 20 elements, it shows weird result.

Comment: Do you want to group by date and sort by gender?

Comment: Yes, but Its not date always the data can differ.The first element can be some name but the structure of the data is same.

Comment: You aren't considering case where `a[0] != b[0]` and sorting by their values

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localeCompare()` to compare string

```js
var myArray = [
  ["2017-01", "Female", "671950.00"],
  ["2017-01", "Male", "322800.00"],
  ["2017-02", "Male", "323977.00"],
  ["2017-02", "Female", "671375.00"],
  ["2017-03", "Male", "326515.00"],
  ["2017-03", "Female", "683646.00"],
  ["2017-04", "Male", "326642.00"],
  ["2017-04", "Female", "684820.00"],
  ["2017-05", "Female", "687627.00"],
  ["2017-05", "Male", "330966.00"],
  ["2017-06", "Male", "330290.00"],
  ["2017-06", "Female", "686022.00"],
  ["2017-07", "Male", "326663.00"],
  ["2017-07", "Female", "679277.00"],
  ["2017-08", "Female", "684451.00"],
  ["2017-08", "Male", "329804.00"],
  ["2017-09", "Female", "686584.00"],
  ["2017-09", "Male", "330300.00"],
  ["2017-10", "Female", "658154.00"],
  ["2017-10", "Male", "316671.00"]
];

myArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a[0] !== b[0]) return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]); //If first element is not the same, compare the first element
  return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);                    //Compare the second element since the first element is the same
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Doc: [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the sorting logic by below and see it will work perfectly.

```
var sortedArray  = myArray.sort(function (a, b) {  
             return a > b ? 1 : -1;
        });
```

See Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrLwvgL6/)